# How to use both paths & branches filter with workflow_run event in Github Action?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions, continuous-deployment

I want to trigger a workflow that deploys the build. I want to make sure of the following:

1. `CI` workflow is completed
2. branch is `develop`
3. there are some changes in `src/**`

```yaml
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ['CI']
    branches: [develop]
    paths: ['src/**']
    types:
      - completed
```

It seems the above approach is not supported , is there any other way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering the `workflows`+`branches` combo should work, but `paths:` does not exist in the `workflow_run` context, you might consider using [`actions/verify-changed-files`](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/verify-changed-files)

That way, you can trigger an intermediate workflow which would check which files have changed.
Then the next step can be run only if the previous step (file check) has succeeded ([using `success()`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/context-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#job-status-check-functions))

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks!